# Query to output unmatched column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two of the columns lets say Country, Country Code. The table can have multiple rows with same country and code. But country and code always have to match. How can I write a query that will find me a list of all rows where country and country code do not match.

If this is the table, I want the query to return row#4.. where Canada does not match with XYZ (it should have been CN).. There is a master list of country and codes in a different table lets say.. tblCountries.

[image]

Comment: How do you expect SQL Server to know that CN is right but ZY is wrong?

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake.. edited the post

Comment: `SELECT * FROM dbo.thistable AS t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblCountries AS c WHERE c.Country = t.Country AND c.CountryCode = t.CountryCode);` That will identify mismatches as well as rows that aren't represented in the countries table at all.

Comment: Thanks Aaron Bertrand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the select statement with the NOT EXISTS operator as suggested by Aaron Bertrand in the comments, or you can use a left join:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM MyTable T
LEFT JOIN TblCountries C ON(T.Country = C.Country AND T.CountryCode = C.CountryCode)
WHERE C.CountryId IS NULL -- Assuming you have a column by that name that's not nullable.
```

Giorgi Nakeuri's answer will also get you the result you are looking for, however, if there is a record in your table that have a country and a code that doesn't even exist in tblCountry then Aaron's answer or mine will return it, but Giorgi's will not.

Answer (score 2):

First of all if there is another table with contry and code then you are breaking normalization principles having same columns in another table.

You can do it like:

```
select * from testTable tt
join Countries c on ((c.Country = tt.Country and c.Code <> tt.Code) 
                      or (c.Code = tt.Code and c.Country <> tt.Country))
```